# Apache URL Rewrite search/replace

Tags: regex, apache, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

How would I match the following request:

/some-file**FR**.html

to the following file:

/some-file**_fr**.html

Here's what I'm using, which is not working. Why isn't it?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} FR\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.+)(FR\.html)$ $1_fr.html
```

Comment: Try [`^(.+)FR(?=\.html) $1_fr`](https://regex101.com/r/XStvMm/1) or `^(.+)FR(\.html)$ $1_fr$2`

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.+)FR\.html$ /$1_fr.html [L,NC,R=301]` should work, if not then post your full .htaccess in question

Comment: you're right. Adding those flags at the end worked

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks OK, but make sure that you have `RewriteEngine on` before
(generally as the first row).

Remember that:

- *RewriteEngine* is intially *off*.
- Using `RewriteEngine off` ... `RewriteEngine on` you can "comment out"
  a part of rewrite rules.

Failing to "switch on" the RewriteEngine (at the start) is one of common errors.